# torchvision and tensorflow-gpu import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, torchvision

Running this:

```
import torchvision
import tensorflow
```

Produces the error:

> SystemError: google/protobuf/pyext/descriptor.cc:354: bad argument to internal function

However, swapping the order of the imports does not cause the error:

```
import tensorflow
import torchvision
```

Why is this happening?

---

Version info:

```
tensorflow-gpu=1.15.0
torchvision==0.5.0
```

Comment: Things were working fine for me on `tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1, torch==1.7.1, torchvision==0.8.2` but upgrading to `torch==1.8.0` seems to give me the same error.

Comment: My guess is that removing and then reinstalling torchvision might help.

Comment: @user3761743, Is your issue resolved as suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `torchvision`.

---

I have opened a ticket on [`tensorflow`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48797). My guess is that the order in which you install `torchvision` matters:

> The fix is either to reinstall `torchvision` or to always import `tensorflow` first, as shown above. The issue is difficult to reproduce since fresh install fixes things. Perhaps it is related to the order in which packages are installed -- perhaps `torchvision` is somehow targeting older `tensorflow`-related libraries... and updating it again fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

This fix:

```
import tensorflow  # BEFORE all other imports

import torchvision
```

It works for me.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48797